# If $f$ is strictly monotone increasing and continuous on $I = [a, b]$ then the image $f(I)$ is an interval $[f(a), f(b)]$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I was reading through some notes online and I saw the following sentence. "Obviously if $f$ is continuous on $I = [a, b]$ then the image
$f(I)$ is an interval $[f(a), f(b)]$."

Assume f is strictly increasing

However, this is not obvious to me.

Can you help?

Comment: Throw away those notes, since $f([-1,1])=[0,1]$ for $f(x)=x^2$ for example. If $f$ is monotone increasing, the statement is true, but it is a deep statement that leans on the completeness of the real numbers.

Comment: This is true under the extra condition that $f$ is increasing. It is not true in general

Comment: This is not true as stated. Maybe there are more conditions, like $f$ being increasing?

Comment: Sorry, it does say if f(x) is strictly increasing to start the paragraph. This changes things I assume?

Comment: However, it is true that the image is $[f(c),f(d)]$ for $c,d\in[a,b]$.

Comment: It's true that the image of $f$ is an (closed, bounded) interval, when $f$ is continuous and its domain is a closed, bounded interval. The false part is *what the interval is*. It's $[min(f), max(f)] = [f(x_{min}), f(x_{max})]$ — $f$ achieves its minimum & maximum (again, by continuity on a compact set).

Comment: @Goose719 yes it does. You can prove this proposition (assuming $f$ strictly increasing) using the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Supposing that f(x) is strictly monotone increasing, it is true, I just don't know how it is obvious? I am missing something.

Comment: Ohh well if $f$ is increasing, not necessarily strictly, then it achieves its maximum at $b$ and its minimum at $a$.

Comment: By the intermediate value theorem, $image(f)$ has the property that for all $y, z \in image(f)$, if $y\le z$  then $[y,z] \subseteq image(f)$.